# Change title of image that's dynamically created from javascript in a chat

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, alt

**Goal**: I am trying to set the alt and title for an img.

**Problem**: The problem is, it is dynamically created in a chat when a user uploads an image. There is no id for the image.

**What I tried**: I tried adding it to the innerhtml but nothing happens when I try to set the title for the image (it displays the English text, not the Spanish). I know the condition is correct because I have translated other static items inside the same if statement. But this img is being dynamically created.  I see some SO articles mentioning jquery. But others say you don't need it and can do this through pure JS.

```
if(locale=='es'){
    openLargerImageMsg = 'Haga clic para abrir una imagen más grande'; //Text I want to display
    document.getElementById('largerImageID').title = openLargerImageMsg;
    document.getElementById('largerImageID').alt = openLargerImageMsg;      
}

var newMsgImg = document.createElement('img');
var newMsgContent = document.createElement('div');

newMsgContent.innerHTML = '<img id="largerImageID" src="/ImgUploads/' + message.UploadedFileName + '" onclick="ShowLargerUploadedFile(\'/ImgUploads/' + message.UploadedFileName + '\');" alt="Click to open larger image" title="Click to open larger image" /><span class="ChatMessageTimestamp">' + message.Timestamp + '</span>';

newMsg.appendChild(newMsgContent);
appendMessage(newMsg);


var appendMessage = function (objMsg) 
        {
            objLiveChatLog.appendChild(objMsg);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you use the `getElementById` function before that you create the element.

I write some test and this should work.

```js
// Fake locale change
locale = `es`;

const genImg = () => {
        
        const newImg = document.createElement(`img`);
        
        newImg.alt = `Click to open a bigger image`;
        
        if (locale == `es`) {
                newImg.alt = `Haga clic para abrir una imagen más grande`;
        }
        
        document.body.appendChild(newImg);
}


document.getElementById(`button`).addEventListener(`click`, genImg);
```

```html
        <button id="button">Click</button>
```